# What does "bytes to encode the instructions" mean?

Tags: c++, c, compilation, encode

I am reading "Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective".
Topic: stages of compilation in C
Preprocessing phase, Compilation phase, Assembly phase and Linker phase.
In Assembly phase this line "This file (the object file) is a binary file containing **17 bytes to encode the instructions** for function main."
I can't understand what the "17 bytes to encode the instructions mean".

Comment: it means that high level instruction took 17 bytes to convert to binary in the object file throught the compiler/assembler

Comment: Function `main()` is not just one instruction, that sentence almost certainly meant *instructions*, plural.

Comment: Even machine code is stored ion zeros and ones (bits and bytes)... so it requires space.

Comment: Linguistic analysis, breaking that sentence into smaller pieces: *This file (the object file) is a binary file. This file contains 17 bytes. Those 17 bytes encode certain instructions. Those instructions came from the `main` function.* (Does that fit the larger context?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without entering in much detail, the result of the compilation is stored in object files. Then, after compiling that function `main`, the result are 17 bytes that are stored in the object file. It says 'encode' because the compiler is "translating" from C++ language to another, which normally is machine code. Depending on the compiler and the target machine/environment you want to compile for, those 17 bytes will probably be different.